# Redirect rendering a blank page when conditionally rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```js
<BrowserRouter>
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <Switch>
            {hasTrialExpired &&
              subscriptionStatus !== ACTIVE && <Redirect exact to={PAYMENTS} />}
            <Route
              exact
              path={PAYMENTS}
              component={PaymentPage}
            />
          </Switch>
        </View>
</BrowserRouter>
```

My payment page looks like this

```js
function PaymentInfoCollectionPage() {

  return (
    <Container>
  ...................
    </Container>
  )
}

const Container = styled.div`
  width: 98%;
  margin: auto;
`
const Link = styled.a`
  color: ${persianGreenColor};
`
export default withRouter(PaymentInfoCollectionPage)
```

When I go straight to the payments path it shows the payment page for a brief second and then changes it to a blank page. When I go to another page the same happens and it get's redirected straight to the blank payments page.
What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be in the way you implemented the redirect logic. Basically as soon as this condition satisfies: **hasTrialExpired &&         subscriptionStatus !== ACTIVE** you'll get redirected to that page on component re-render (whenever it changes the state) and this may be happening again and again within a fraction of time so that the page doesn't have time to render the content and you keep seeing the blank page.

The solution is:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(hasTrialExpired && subscriptionStatus !== ACTIVE) 
   history.push(PAYMENTS) // or any other function responsible for route redirection
}, [hasTrialExpired, subscriptionStatus]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just taking a guess here but you may be confusing the Switch component or you have a loop going on.  What is the initial path they are coming in to?  Once they hit that path which route is being used?
Can you try it like this:

```
    let notTrialOrActive = hasTrialExpired && subscriptionStatus !== ACTIVE
    return (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path={PAYMENTS}>
            {notTrialOrActive ? <Redirect to={Payments} /> : 
            <SomeOtherAccountPage />}
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </View>
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
```